# What happens if my system is improperly shutdown?

Tags: shutdown

I have Lubuntu 13.10 in my seven-year-old PC with 512MB RAM and an Intel Dual Core 3.00Ghz x 2 Processor. I sometimes unplug it from the power while it is running, in an emergency situation. Please tell me if there may be any adverse consequences of manually powering off my computer while it is running.

Comment: your HDD will crash

Comment: why posted to unix and linux? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106836/what-happens-if-we-do-improper-shutdown-in-lubunmtu-13-10

Answer (score 4):

Well, the real question here is "what could not happen" because of happening bad stuff doing hard shutdowns there are many:

- Data loss
- Data corruption
- Degradation of the hard disk plates
- Filesystem inconcistency
- some weirdness about services
- etc.

Why there isn't more detailed and technical information? Well, because nobody does, and you shouldn't either. BTW, this isn't exclusive to Ubuntu or Lubuntu or any operating system, all machines should be properly shut down with their pre-established methods.

Answer (score 1):

Improperly shutting down your computer can cause some harmful effects for your software. Though newer operating systems are better equipped to handle an improper shut down, there are still negative effects associated with it. Computers should be shut down improperly only when there are no other options available, such as in the case of a your computer freezing.
What Happens?

> If a computer is improperly shut down, for instance by a power failure, then registry files cease operation while they are still performing a function. This is the main cause of potential problems. Any applications or processes that were running at the time of shut down also will be interrupted and any files that were not saved will be lost. Any settings that may have been changed just prior to shut down also will most likely not take effect.